# Awk script - ARGV

Tags: awk, argv

i am trying to print the first argument which i input when calling the program, but it's not working. 
Any help, please?

```
#!/bin/bash -f
awk '
    BEGIN{
        print "argc: "ARGC
        print "argv0: "ARGV[0]
        print "argv1: "ARGV[1]      
    }
'
```

run using: `./progName.awk "data"`

but 'data' is not being displayed.

Comment: As an aside: the  `-f` makes `bash` run with pathname expansion (globbing) disabled (it may _look_ like the option that makes `sed` and `awk` read their program from a file, but in `bash` it means something different; to simply make it read the script file, _no_ option is needed at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the last line to be:

```
' "$@"
```

Right now you aren't passing any args to awk.

Unrelated and will not change any functionality but change the name of your script from `./progName.awk` to `./progName.sh` or similar as it is NOT an awk script, it is a shell script which just happens to call awk to execute an awk script. You could replace the awk script with perl or ruby or whatever and it would not change the fact that what you have is an executable shell script.

Comment: What if I want to use this input to compare against some column? Can it be done?

Comment: Yes, of course it can. Post a new question with sample input and expected output if you're stuck on some part of doing that. Meanwhile - what I posted above IS the answer to your question so remember to click on the check mark next to it to accept it.

Comment: The error message is very clear - you are telling awk to parse a file named "ownerName" but you do not have a file named "ownerName" in the directory from which you are executing the script. What were you expecting to happen? Look, there's clearly something you're trying to do now that is unrelated to the original question you asked and which I answered. As I said before, post a new question.